# Excess <div> and <script> tags in front-end for EmberJS app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on the front-end of an EmberJS App. Ember spits out a lot of `<script>` and `<div>` tags that can make styling and de-bugging particularly tricky for front-end development.

For example a simple list of items can sometimes have 2 `<script>` tags before and after every `<li>` and multiple `<div>` tags within the `<li>`.

Working with the developer I understand the necessity of these, however it makes doing simple tasks like `:last-child`, 100% height `<div>`'s and simple de-bugging in the Chrome Inspector very tricky. These are just some examples.

How are other developers working around this? Are there any solutions available to make the front-end work a little easier?

Comment: see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/446, you can use :last-child-of-type instead of :last-child, and change the tagName or use collectionView to avoid some extra <div> and <script> tags

Answer (score 3):

Those tags are needed by ember to maintain DOM.

Nevertheless, for collections rendering, you can use `{{view Ember.CollectionView ...}}` instead of `{{#each}}` helper to avoid items associated `<script>` tags *(see [doc here](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.CollectionView&src=false))*.

In others cases, there is no real alternative. Maybe `{{unbound}}` for placeholder which do not have to be bound...